# which app does anaconda used to run .py scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, dronekit-python, dronekit

I was trying to run dronekit-SITL in windows so I downloaded the anaconda so that I can use py-2.7 separately, but when I try to run mavproxy.py script, it shows up a dialog box to choose an app to run the .py file, and when I click on any of the apps nothing happens.

[this will show what my problem is actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9cyE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jupyter Notebook**

it will be installed along with anaconda

Comment: I have edited my question, do look in the picture maybe you can help, thank you.

Comment: So try putting 'py' or 'python' before the your file name

Comment: "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'mavproxy.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory",  this error comes when i added py before it

Comment: where is your mavproxy.py? you should run the cmd from that location.Also make sure you have set environment path t python

Comment: thank you i solved it by reaching the location using cd command and then running it.:)